# To send message body using sendEmail() method of google script

Tags: google-apps-script

MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message, {  htmlBody: message,  cc: 'internal1@email.com' });  to send email where the message is string value not an html body, what should be passed as a parameter for sending string message

Comment: I don't get, could you please update your question, so others could [reproduce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stackoverflow. you can still use MailApp

in this version all the variables are strings

```js
MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body)
```

You can try this simple example to see it work

```js
string email = "youremail@domain.com";
string title = "Test Title";
string body = "Test body";

MailApp.sendEmail(email, title, body);
```

The `sendEmail` method also has other more advanced options the GAS IDE showed you which is what got you confused.

Please refer to the [docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendEmail(Object)) for more info

Answer (score 0):

- The simplest way to send an email is to use [sendEmail(recipient, subject, body)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendemailrecipient,-subject,-body):

```js
MailApp.sendEmail("recipient-email", "Your subject", "Your message body");
```

Now, if you want to add `cc`, while keeping the message body a string, you have two options:

- [sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, options)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendemailrecipient,-subject,-body,-options). Just like you did, but without providing the `htmlBody` property:

```js
MailApp.sendEmail("recipient-email", "Your subject", "Your message body", { cc: "your-cc-email" });
```

- [sendEmail(message)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendemailmessage). In this case, you have to provide a JS object as a parameter, with the properties you want to add (just provide `body`, and not `htmlBody`):

```js
MailApp.sendEmail({
  to: "recipient-email",
  subject: "Your subject",
  body: "Your body",
  cc: "your-cc-email"
});
```